# Pandas datareader failure

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get all the stocks from sp500 to a folder in csv format.

Now while scanning the sp500 everything works great but it seems to be that in some cases the index referred to date is missing because stock doesn't exist or has no date for a specific time, whatever I tried to change startdate and enddate but no effect - in en earlier post I was said to filter those dates with an exception but due to python is new land for me I was like an alien... is there someone who can help me?

If this error occurs:

> /home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python /home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/get_sp500_beautifulsoup_intro.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
>   return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/get_sp500_beautifulsoup_intro.py", line 44, in get_data_from_yahoo
>   df = web.DataReader (ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
>   return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 387, in DataReader
>   session=session,
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 251, in read
>   df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 165, in _read_one_data
>   prices["Date"] = to_datetime(to_datetime(prices["Date"], unit="s").dt.date)
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2995, in **getitem**
>   indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
>   File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/get_sp500_beautifulsoup_intro.py", line 57, in 
>       get_data_from_yahoo()
>     File "/home/mu351i/PycharmProjects/untitled/get_sp500_beautifulsoup_intro.py", line 48, in get_data_from_yahoo
>       except RemoteDataError:
>   NameError: name 'RemoteDataError' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

```
how would you avoid this by changing this code?
```

import datetime as dt
import os
import pickle

import bs4 as bs
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import requests

def safe_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

```
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker=row.findAll('td')[0].text.strip()
    tickers.append(ticker)

with open('sp500tickers.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(tickers,f)

return tickers
```

safe_sp500_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers=safe_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open('sp500tickers.pickle', 'rb') as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

```
if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
    os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

start = dt.datetime(1999,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,12,19)

for ticker in tickers:

    try:
        if not os.path.exists ('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format (ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader (ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv ('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format (ticker))
        else:
            print ("Ticker from {} already availablle".format (ticker))
    except RemoteDataError:
        print ("No information for ticker '%s'" % i)
        continue
    except KeyError:
        print("no Date for Ticker: " +ticker )
        continue
```

get_data_from_yahoo()

```
A Commentator asked for some DATA Sample, well this is DATA form TSLA.csv
```

Date,High,Low,Open,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2010-06-29,25.0,17.540000915527344,19.0,23.889999389648438,18766300,23.889999389648438
2010-06-30,30.420000076293945,23.299999237060547,25.790000915527344,23.829999923706055,17187100,23.829999923706055
2010-07-01,25.920000076293945,20.270000457763672,25.0,21.959999084472656,8218800,21.959999084472656
2010-07-02,23.100000381469727,18.709999084472656,23.0,19.200000762939453,5139800,19.200000762939453
2010-07-06,20.0,15.829999923706055,20.0,16.110000610351562,6866900,16.110000610351562
2010-07-07,16.6299991607666,14.979999542236328,16.399999618530273,15.800000190734863,6921700,15.800000190734863
2010-07-08,17.520000457763672,15.569999694824219,16.139999389648438,17.459999084472656,7711400,17.459999084472656
2010-07-09,17.899999618530273,16.549999237060547,17.579999923706055,17.399999618530273,4050600,17.399999618530273
2010-07-12,18.06999969482422,17.0,17.950000762939453,17.049999237060547,2202500,17.049999237060547
2010-07-13,18.639999389648438,16.899999618530273,17.389999389648438,18.139999389648438,2680100,18.139999389648438
2010-07-14,20.149999618530273,17.760000228881836,17.940000534057617,19.84000015258789,4195200,19.84000015258789
2010-07-15,21.5,19.0,19.940000534057617,19.889999389648438,3739800,19.889999389648438
2010-07-16,21.299999237060547,20.049999237060547,20.700000762939453,20.639999389648438,2621300,20.639999389648438

```
Please provide constructive feedback because I'new here.

Thanks :)
```

Comment: If you are only using Pandas to read the data and spit it out as a csv file, maybe you should parse the data yourself and use the csv module to write the file(s) - you will have finer control over  catching and handling errors for *non-compliant* data. `...python is new land for me i was like an alien..` - this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Dig in; read; experiment; learn. When asking questions about code that relies on data, you should include a minimal example of the data with the question. - [mcve].

Comment: im now sitting 3 hrs on digging how to fix that but all of the sudden i still dont have a clue so i decided to ask for help.... and i would be glad if you could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `import`

Add the following `import` at the top of your script

`from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError`

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies")[0]

sort = pd.DataFrame(df).sort_values(by=['Date first added'])
sort['Date first added'] = pd.to_datetime(sort['Date first added'])

start_date = '1-1-1999'
end_date = '11-12-2019'

mask = (sort['Date first added'] > start_date) & (
    sort['Date first added'] <= end_date)

sort = sort.loc[mask]

pd.DataFrame(sort).to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Output: [View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/03490ea5dde2581a38d640c27a9260cc/result.csv)

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: thank you but this answer does not provide the help i wanted because im following a python tutorial which uses this certain way i provided.

Comment: i just don't understand your question, i followed the part of `i want to get all the stocks from sp500 to a folder in csv format`

Comment: @kiffz anyway i updated my code for your preferable target. good luck